# ASP.NET MVC5 doesn't create MySQL database except break at the initializer

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC5. Using the following tutorial:
http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-setup-mvc5-website-mysql-entity-framework-6-code-first-vs2013/

I'm using the following code:

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBContext()
            : base("MyDBContextConnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new MyDBInitializer());
        }

            public DbSet<User> Users{get;set;}
            public DbSet<History> Histories{get;set;}
            public DbSet<Place> Places{get;set;}
            public DbSet<Review> Reviews{get;set;}
            public DbSet<Type> Types{get;set;}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
```

The web.config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDBContextConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=******;database=KorulottemDB;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

Unfortunately doesn't create the database except I break at the initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new MyDBInitializer());
```

and click on the "The function evaluation requires all threads to run".

[image]

The database appears on the server in this case but without tables.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Code First approach, i recommend you to use [Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) too. To enabel that you can run the following command in Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migration -ProjectName <YourDataLayer>
```

You should try to use Package Manager Console, in Visual Studio, and run the following command:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName <YourDataLayer>
```

Comment: @Subalfa any progress?

Comment: Hello Pedro, Thanks for your reply. I could use the command this way: **Update-Database -ProjectName:MyProjectName**  and the got the following: **Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Korulottem'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).**

Comment: continuation: enabled the Migration and then added Migration. Finally update-database. Unfortunately the InnoDB feature of MySQL doesn't work. I will try to solve it and we will see.

Comment: Thank you very much Pedro finally your suggestion worked!